# Dnf install kernel doesn't install kernel to /boot

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, dnf

I have the same problem as reported at https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/73766/fedora-22-not-using-newer-kernal-after-dnf-update/
NOTE: the answers to that posting are not addressing the poster's question, which I'll reformulate as follows:

When I try to update to a newer kernel, i.e. from `4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64`
to `4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64`, the install succeeds but the
`vmlinuz-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64`
file doesn't show up in `/boot`. Note that `/lib/modules` contains the `4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64` modules, but the kernel isn't copied into `/boot`. I've tried also:

```
dnf -y reinstall kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24
```

with the following output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:30 ago on Sun Jan  1 14:39:27 2017.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package        Arch           Version                    Repository       Size
================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 kernel         x86_64         4.8.15-200.fc24            updates          76 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================

Total download size: 76 k
Downloading Packages:
kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64.rpm                80 kB/s |  76 kB     00:00    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            38 kB/s |  76 kB     00:01     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Reinstalling: kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64                               1/2 
  Erasing     : kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64                               2/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64                               1/2 
  Verifying   : kernel-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64                               2/2 

Reinstalled:
  kernel.x86_64 4.8.15-200.fc24                                                 

Complete!
```

But still no `/boot/vlimuz-4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64` file. Note that /boot is in a filesystem with 190 GB of free space. I also tried `dnf clean metadata` and `dnf clean all`, but that made no difference.
NOTE also the very small size of the kernel `rpm` file. Broken repo file? Here are my fedora repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1253 Aug 13 07:44 fedora.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  689 Aug 13 07:44 fedora-cisco-openh264.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1270 Aug 13 07:44 fedora-updates.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1328 Aug 13 07:44 fedora-updates-testing.repo
```

Comment: Did you restart the machine to see if the change was effective?  Is it possible that it simply put the file elsewhere?

Comment: What's your full listing of `/boot`?  (`ls -la /boot/.`)

Comment: @Gordon,This kernel package was not correct.Did you see the size of kernel package (76KB)?. You can try to download it manually from rpm.pbone.net for fc24.

Comment: Julie: here is the output of ls -la /boot:

Comment: Please don't recommend downloading things from rpm.pbone.net. There's literally no telling what you might get. Use a [Fedora Mirror](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/).

Comment: Did you do anything to possibly remove files in `/boot`? What happens if you reinstall `kernel-core-4.8.15-200`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `rpm -ql kernel`. You will see `(contains no files)` (possibly multiple times if you have multiple kernels installed). For the past few releases, that's just a "meta package" which pulls in `kernel-core` and `kernel-modules`. That's so you can just install `kernel-core`, if all you need is a minimal kernel to boot in a virtualized environment.

I'm not quite sure how you have the ``` kernel`` package installed without the corresponding ```kernel-core`, but I'm pretty sure that's what's causing what you are seeing now.